# Distributed event bus with vertx

Tags: vert.x, consumer, event-bus, sender

I want to know if there is a standard distributed event bus in Vertx to use for communication between a sender in a VM and a consumer in another VM without using a cluster manager.

Thanks

Comment: What did you find when researching this yourself? http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/ceylon/#event_bus talks about the distributed event model. Is there a specific question you have that isn't addressed by the official docs and examples? That is, it is unclear what specific limitations, if any, you have found with the current docs and API, and what specific question you are asking that goes beyond your initial research.

Answer (score 2):

> without using a cluster manager.

No, the cluster manager is the standard way to distribute event bus calls efficiently between vertices of any kind, especially using conveniences like `vertx.sharedData()`.

Answer (score 0):

Not without a cluster manager, but it's pretty easy to set up with the cluster manager. Just go to the [starter app generator](https://start.vertx.io/) and select "Clustering" dependency in the sidebar. You can generate working code with any of the 4 cluster managers:

Hazelcast Cluster Manager

Infinispan Cluster Manager

Apache Ignite Cluster Manager

Apache Zookeper Cluster Manager